# Future PhD applications and COVID -19

Tags: application, covid-19

How do you think next year's PhD applications would be affected by the COVID-19? Will we be seeing less numbers or more? Will they be more competitive?

Edit: mainly asking for applicants to the US and UK.

Comment: You need to name your country.  Each country has a different process.

Comment: It's too early to speculate, considering some plausible worst-case scenarios have people largely confined to their homes for another year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to be certain about the future.

- There will be more positions because of government stimulus spending.
- More students will apply for PhD programs because they cannot find jobs.
- As a result of chaos, fewer students will complete the eligibility requirements.

The most likely net effect is more applicants for more positions, but they will be less prepared.

Comment: The opposite could equally happen: economy crunches, and money will be scarce. "It is hard to make predictions, especially about the future." was the original quote ;-)

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Money is never scarce for central banks.  They create it.  Countries that do not have central banks are often not good places to get a PhD anyway.

Comment: The Central Banks may create the *paper* that we call "money". They do not create the *value* that we mean by "money".